# Clicking on the label should close a tab which doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to close tabs by clicking on the tab label.
I added a click event listener to the label but this doesn't work.
What di I need to do to get this working?

```js
const labels = document.querySelectorAll('label');
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[role="tab"]');
labels.forEach(label => label.addEventListener('click', handleLabelClick ))

function handleLabelClick(event) {
    tab = event.currentTarget.previousElementSibling;
    if (tab.checked = "checked") {
        closeAllTabs();
    }
}

function closeAllTabs() {
    tabs.forEach(tab => {
        tab.checked = false;
    });
}
```

```css
/**
 * Tabs
 */
 .dc-tabs {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.dc-tabs label {
    order: 1; 
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    margin-right: 0.2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  background: #90CAF9;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background ease 0.2s;
}
.dc-tabs .dc-tab {
  order: 99; 
  flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
}
.dc-tabs input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}
.dc-tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background: #fff;
}
.dc-tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .dc-tab {
    display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 20em) {
  .dc-tabs .dc-tab,
  .dc-tabs label {
    order: initial;
  }
  .dc-tabs label {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0.2rem;
  }
}

/**
 * Generic Styling
*/
body {
  background: #eee;
  min-height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 10vh;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 112%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dc-tabs">
        <input type="radio" role="tab" name="tabs" id="tabone" checked="checked">
        <label for="tabone">Tab One</label>
        <div class="dc-tab">
          <h1>Tab One Content</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
        </div>
        
        <input type="radio" role="tab" name="tabs" id="tabtwo">
        <label for="tabtwo">Tab Two</label>
        <div class="dc-tab">
          <h1>Tab Two Content</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        
        <input type="radio" role="tab" name="tabs" id="tabthree">
        <label for="tabthree">Tab Three</label>
        <div class="dc-tab">
          <h1>Tab Three Content</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <script src='./accordion.js'></script>
```

Comment: I don't understand the need for JavaScript. The tabs are working without the JavaScript because of input radio button. In the JavaScript the if condition is wrong you need to use double equal to.

Comment: But I need to close a tab on mobile without scrolling and clicking on another tab. This doesn’t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default behaviour of the event in `handleLabelClick` when tabs have to be closed. Otherwise it just closes them and then the `click` event continues on its way triggers the default behaviour, which is to open the tab for the clicked label.

```
function handleLabelClick(event) {
  const tab = event.currentTarget.previousElementSibling;
  if (tab.checked) {
    event.preventDefault();
    closeAllTabs();
  }
}
```

Notice also that if you want to compare values, you need to use `==` or `===`, the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) will give you more insight.
Additionally, `tab.checked` returns a boolean, so it is by itself enough for the conditional check.

Finally, I also made `tab` a constant, in order to avoid it being set as global variable.